# Finding the maximum of absolute numbers

Tags: c#, arrays, max

Is there any quick way of turning all the members of an array into absolute and find the max number among them?
For example in this array:

-100 25 43

The max is 43, but I want to get 100 from my code. Is there's any simple/fast method that I can use to find max regardless of its sign? or do I have to use a for loop to turn all the array members into absolute and then find the max among them?

Comment: Suppose one of the values is int.MinValue. It has no absolute value that fits into an int. You should state what behaviour you want in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
var numbers = new[] { -100, 25, 43 };

var absoluteMax = numbers.Select(x => Math.Abs(x)).Max();
```

I get `100` as requested.

Do be careful if one of your numbers is `int.MinValue` then you get an `OverflowException` - "Negating the minimum value of a twos complement number is invalid."

Comment: What happens if one of the values is int.MinValue? Is what happens the desired behaviour?

Comment: Thanks @EricLippert. I've learnt so much from you over the years. But please don't make me overly paranoid about my coding. ;-)

Comment: You want to be *just paranoid enough* I suppose. :-)  Really the issue I am pointing out here is not that your logic is wrong, but rather that the problem itself is underspecified.

Comment: Thank you very much @Enigmativity :)

Comment: this is creating an intermediate List in memory. Is this comparable on performance to make :  return Max( abs(list.min) , abs(list.max) )  ??

Comment: @javirs - My code is **not** making an intermediate list. What makes you think that? My code would be twice as fast as the code you're suggesting.

Comment: number.Select(xxxx) generates an intermediate list .. If Im right (I might not XD)

Comment: @javirs - No, it does **not** generate an intermediate list. It simply iterates the original **without** creating a list of its own.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
int[] array = {-100, 25, 43};
int max = array.Select(Math.Abs).Max();
```

Comment: Definitely `Select` and `Max` extension methods are just a neat way to do a for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Well think about it. You have a list of numbers. You need to find the (absolute) maximum. Can you think of a way of finding the maximum without checking all of them? If you check the first 2, can you confidently conclude that you found the maximum, without checking the rest of the array? You can't. Thus, you need to check every single number.

A basic `for` loop would do. You don't have any better way than looping. Sure, you can use LINQ or other API's that hide the loop from you, but fundamentally that's what they do.

Comment: Yes you're right, LINQ does the same thing but I was looking for a clear method for it, so I won't have to write (probably) inefficient code for it.